# What does the Scrabble board look like in foreign languages?

Tags: scrabble

What does the Scrabble board look like in foreign languages?
I recently saw a 19x19 Scrabble board, which might be used in German, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The board is the same shape in every language as far as I know

What changes are letters and letter distributions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions

**Welsh** is a notable one:

[image]

Edit: A 21x21 board apparently exists and seems to be a licensed variant of the game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Scrabble

[image]
*Credit: Kevin Marks from San Jose, USA - Super Scrabble, CC BY 2.0*

Comment: I can't access it at all. But I really saw a 19 by 19 grid somewhere.

Comment: I don't doubt you. I also don't think it was a standard variant of any language edition of Scrabble. A quick search found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Scrabble

Comment: I can't access it.

Comment: I tried using the Wiki Hacker website.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the different language variants of Scrabble is predominantly the letter distribution and values, the board dimensions always stay the same.

There are however a number of non-core variants of scrabble that have boards with different dimensions, including [Super Scrabble](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11182/super-scrabble) with a *21x21* board and Scrabble Junior with *[11x11](http://www.mattelgames.com/games/fr-fr/strategy/scrabble-jr)*, *13x13* and *15x15* variants.

In addition to these official Scrabble branded variants, there are also a few non-Scrabble games like [Scrabeo](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/12747/scarabeo) or [Slovodel](https://www.amazon.com.au/Russian-Board-Scrabble-Slovodel-Erudite/dp/B07F2C9QCS) that look similar, but have different dimensions (*17x17* for Scrabeo, *16x16* for Slovodel).

As it was in a different language it's entirely possible what you saw was a competing game, rather than a Scrabble game.

Answer (score 0):

My Aunt gifted me a Dutch Scrabble game many years ago. The board was identical to the English one - but the letter mix was very very different: 20 "E"s instead of 12 and 3 "Z"s worth 2 points each rather than 1 of 10 points.

I suspect that you happened upon a double-board. 15^2 = 225 and 19^2 = 361 so that board had almost twice as many squares as the standard one. Removing a small number of agreed letters from a double set would have made a quite playable game with a greater skill-to-luck ratio than the standard.